# How to configure .netcore proxy connection to webpack to use HTTP not HTTPS

Tags: c#, webpack, .net-core

I have a dotnet core app that is configured to use HTTPS and I have configured it to `UseSpa` but I am seeing a lot of errors in the console and I believe it is due to something (either the proxy or webpack) using https instead of http.

`VM3850:1 GET https://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1564649931199 net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I have tried to set https and http2 to false within the webpack.config devServer section.
I have tried using `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${opts.host}:${opts.port}/`

but it is still using https

#### my dotnet core config

````
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:8080");
            });```
````

Ultimately I am trying to get access my site on https at https://localhost:5001 and have it use the proxy to communicate to my SPA at http://localhost:8080.

If it set webpack to use `https`, UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer to use "https://localhost:8080" and trust the certificate it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on this and bit the bullet.

I turned on HTTPS and configured a self signed certificate for use locally.

I created a script which may help people if they are trying to do the same thing.

https://gist.github.com/4imble/4aafecf261bfc8732f235498be6a3fa2